# Django index lookup with a forloop.counter0

Tags: python, html, django

I have this for loop that creates a Django template element, which stores the information of 1 row of the query table.

```
{% for user in ml_users %}
<div class="container"> .........
    <p><a id="event" href="#"><strong>Name-</strong> {{ user.name }} </a></p>
</div>
```

Now for some reason, that I will not go into, I need to print out `{{user.name.0}}` on the first iteration, `{{user.name.1}}` on the second iteration and so on ... Is there a way to somehow put a for loop counter where the index is? It should be something like:

```
{{user.name.forloop.counter0}}
```

Comment: Did you try `user.name.forloop.counter0`?  What did it do?

Comment: You will need to write a template filter that accepts the index and applies it to it's argument.

Comment: @John Gordon
 Didn't do anything ! Empty space where the value was supposed to be :)

Comment: I think you probably *do* want to get into the reason for this, as it doesn't seem like the code would make much sense. Isn't `name` just a string with the user's name?

Comment: I didnt write the reason to simplify the question ! The reason i needed this was that an HTML div was created for each member of an array_aggreagate column. So each row creates a block and within it alot of divs are created based on the number of aggregated elements (list length) 
and all of those elements can be for instance names. Imagine an array with 3 names {John, Dave, Peter}. When a div was created for the iteration of John i needed to print John,  which would go {user.name.0} . For the iteration of the 2nd element  a 2nd div was created in which i needed to print Dave {user.name.1} ..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `forloop.counter` in your `for` loop.